# Is the bootstrap tabs feature not working because of my css files?

Tags: html, css, tabs, bootstrap-5, sidebar

I want to use bootstrap tabs in the sidebar on my website, but I can't use it because unfortunately it doesn't work when I put tabs in the related sidebar-parsel-liste class.

When I add the tabs tags in the code anywhere outside of the sidebar-parcel-list class, the code works fine and I can switch between tabs.

[inside sidebar-parsel-liste](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdJUm.png)

MY CODES;

```
<div id="sidebar-parsel-liste" class="sidebar-parsel-liste">
    <div class="card m-0">
        <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center;">
            <h4 class="card-title"> <i class="ti-angle-left"
                    style="padding-right: 4px; font-size: 14px; cursor: pointer;"></i>Parsel
                Kartı</h4>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"
                onclick="showSuccessAlert()">Kaydet</button>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <!-- sidebar butonlar -->
        <div class="button-list">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info m-b-10 m-l-5">Bina</button>
            <button type="button" id="degerlemeKarti"
                class="btn btn-sm btn-info m-b-10 m-l-5">Değerleme</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info m-b-10 m-l-5">Mülk Bilgi</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info m-b-10 m-l-5">Rapor</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info m-b-10 m-l-5">Takbis</button>
        </div>

        <!-- navbar başlangıcı tabs -->
        <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title m-b-40">Tab with dropdown</h4>
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab"
                        href="#home5" role="tab" aria-controls="home5" aria-expanded="true"
                        aria-selected="false"><span class="hidden-sm-up"><i
                                class="ti-home"></i></span> <span
                            class="hidden-xs-down">Home</span></a> </li>
                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab"
                        href="#profile5" role="tab" aria-controls="profile"
                        aria-selected="false"><span class="hidden-sm-up"><i
                                class="ti-user"></i></span> <span
                            class="hidden-xs-down">Profile</span></a></li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle active" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"
                        role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="hidden-sm-up"><i class="ti-email"></i></span> <span
                            class="hidden-xs-down">Dropdown</span>
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" x-placement="bottom-start"
                        style="position: absolute; transform: translate3d(0px, 39px, 0px); top: 0px; left: 0px; will-change: transform;">
                        <a class="dropdown-item active show" id="dropdown1-tab" href="#dropdown1"
                            role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="dropdown1"
                            aria-selected="true" aria-expanded="true">@fat</a> <a
                            class="dropdown-item" id="dropdown2-tab" href="#dropdown2" role="tab"
                            data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="dropdown2">@mdo</a> </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content tabcontent-border p-20" id="myTabContent">
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="home5" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
                    <p>0</p>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile5" role="tabpanel"
                    aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
                    <p>1</p>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade active show" id="dropdown1" role="tabpanel"
                    aria-labelledby="dropdown1-tab">
                    <p>2</p>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="dropdown2" role="tabpanel"
                    aria-labelledby="dropdown2-tab">
                    <p>3</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

</div>
```

how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Need more code, the code you posted actually works fine, so is necessary the entire part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#home-tab-pane" role="tab" aria-controls="home-tab-pane" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link " id="profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#profile-tab-pane" role="tab" aria-controls="profile-tab-pane" aria-selected="true">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#tab1" id="tab1-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#tab1-tab-pane" role="tab" aria-controls="tab1-tab-pane" aria-selected="true">Tab 1</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#tab2" id="tab2-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#tab2-tab-pane" role="tab" aria-controls="tab2-tab-pane" aria-selected="true">tab 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home-tab-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab" tabindex="0">Home</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile-tab-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab" tabindex="0">Profile</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab1-tab-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab1-tab" tabindex="0">Tab 1</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2-tab-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab2-tab" tabindex="0">Tab 2</div>
</div>
```

This demo code in work bootstrap tab feature and,
I am using Bootstrap 5.3 and this code should solve your problem.

Thanks.